# Waiting for Serial write to finish before continuing

Tags: c, serial-port

I am attempting to talk with an encoder over the UART port on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I have disabled the Bluetooth on the Pi to enable full use of the UART port and am talking at 2000000b/s.

I have verified this with an oscilloscope, but the problem that I am running into is that I must set a GPIO pin on the Raspberry Pi to high after the write has completely finished. Right now the write will always write just fine but the pin that I need to set will always go high in the middle of the write.

```
int sfd = open("/dev/serial0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY); 
wiringPiSetup();
pinMode(21, OUTPUT);
struct termios options;
tcgetattr(sfd, &options);
cfsetspeed(&options, B2000000);
cfmakeraw(&options);
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
options.c_cflag |= CREAD;
options.c_cc[VTIME]=1; 
options.c_cc[VMIN]=100;
tcsetattr(sfd, TCSANOW, &options);
char buf[] = {"T"};
digitalWrite(21, LOW);
int count = write(sfd, buf,strlen(buf));
digitalWrite(21, HIGH);
```

I would like the gpio pin to go high after the write has completely finished

Comment: How about `tcdrain`?

Comment: That does seem to work but it delays the line from being toggled for around 30 ms after it is called with any transmission length of 4 or higher and sometimes even 3 and with the encoder that i am using i need to toggle it 18 microseconds after the transmission finishes.

Comment: What's your baud rate?

Comment: I am using a baud rate of 2000000